# calculate the percentage total in completed tasks mysql

Tags: mysql, percentage

I need to group and get the percentage completed in true in a MySQL query

```
id type completed
1   4    true
2   4    false
3   3    false
4   5    true
5   5    true
```

Result

```
type   completed
4        %50
3        %0
5        %100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    type,
    100.0 * AVG(completed = 'true') AS completed
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    type;
```

### Demo

Comment: It is working in the demo.  Your data has a problem.

Comment: Yes, it's true, all the values were true, I got confused, it works perfect, thank you.